# Exception draw text Android 4.4

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Where button back action, I'm having this exception while rendering my view,this exception has occurred on Android 4.4, I tested it on a 8.0 and it ran normally.
also remembering that it happens sometimes, not always, but I still worry about how many times it happens.

```
android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers
GLES20Canvas.java - line 1421
java.lang.StackOverflowError
android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers GLES20Canvas.java:1421
android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawText GLES20Canvas.java:1251
android.text.Layout.drawText Layout.java:345
android.text.Layout.draw Layout.java:205
android.widget.TextView.onDraw TextView.java:5165
android.view.View.draw View.java:14473
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.widget.ListView.drawChild ListView.java:3363
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw AbsListView.java:2458
android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw ListView.java:3358
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.widget.AbsListView.draw AbsListView.java:3817
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2947
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getHardwareLayerDisplayList View.java:13396
android.view.View.getHardwareLayer View.java:13124
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13335
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild DrawerLayout.java:1367
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw FrameLayout.java:472
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13364
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.View.draw View.java:14190
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild ViewGroup.java:3103
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw ViewGroup.java:2940
android.view.View.draw View.java:14476
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw FrameLayout.java:472
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw PhoneWindow.java:2329
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13369
android.view.View.getDisplayList View.java:13411
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList HardwareRenderer.java:1578
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw HardwareRenderer.java:1457
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw ViewRootImpl.java:2385
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw ViewRootImpl.java:2257
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals ViewRootImpl.java:1887
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal ViewRootImpl.java:1000
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run ViewRootImpl.java:5674
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run Choreographer.java:771
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks Choreographer.java:574
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame Choreographer.java:544
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run Choreographer.java:757
android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:733
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:95
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:149
android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:5061
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative Method.java
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java:515
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run ZygoteInit.java:787
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:603
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main NativeStart.java
```

also remembering that it happens sometimes, not always, but I still worry about how many times it happens.

Comment: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` : Without any code it is hard to help, but you definitely have a recursion issue in a View's draw routine.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 15:35:47.161 E/AndroidRuntime(18515): Process: solutions.infinitus.clubber, PID: 18515
09-10 15:35:47.161 E/AndroidRuntime(18515): java.lang.StackOverflowError